What (relatively-recent) anime movie involved a child waking up in a village without memories
I think the main character was a young girl, I think she just wakes up in a rural Japanese village, and she's treated as a visiting relative/grandchild or something.
She slowly realizes that she doesn't remember how she came to be here.
There's some other children she meets and interacts with, eventually there's a scene with some festival with fireflies or lamps or something (I remember something about all the children going into the forest at night), and eventually she goes back to her original place/time, but then sees the town from the side of the road or something? And then the movie ends, I think she may meet someone from the village that she had met before (although I remember something about the village becoming uninhabited because of a dam or something, might be getting confused with higurashi)
Relatively-recent would mean in the last ~5-7 years

This world she went to; was it full of magic and mythical creatures?

Nah, it was (mostly?) normal.

Not Spirited Away then. Where did you see this movie? Can you say anything specific about the style of animation? Was it dubbed to english?

Nah, it was subbed, I downloaded it. Doubt it was localized, but who knows.

Don't really remember much about the animation

http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/all?year=2000&to_year=2017&include_tags=107

Nice site, I would have thought I'd find my answer http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/all?year=2009&to_year=2016&include_types=2&include_tags=265 but no such luck.

I swear I saw it recently in an Internet community. Hold on...

Probably not it, but try Hotarubi no mori e. It has fantasy elements though.

Nah, it wasn't that. Iirc the only fantasy elements were how she got 'transported', while she was there, it was pretty normal iirc

Is it Kaguya-hime no Monogatari ("The Tale of The Princess Kagyya").
Setting is in rural Japan and girl goes back to her home in the end, there is also a parade with children singing when that happens.

Link-only answers are frowned upon on StackExchange - if the link goes down, your answer is gone. Could you explain why you believe this anime matches the description?

Welcome to Movies & TV! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.
